# Problem removing telegram bot custom keyboard

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot

I'm using Google Apps Script to program a Telegram bot. The bot initiates a custom keyboard at some point to get input from the user in a private chat situation. I would like to be able to then remove the custom keyboard completely so that the user has no way of bringing it back. Declaring the keyboard as one-time doesn't do the trick because the keyboard is technically still accessible this way. I've found and been struggling with the **ReplyKeyboardRemove** for a while now. Don't quite know how to word the request.This is my code

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/ReplyKeyboardRemove?remove_keyboard=true");
```

but it doesn't kill the keyboard. I'm at a loss. Please, help out.